# How do i show links and more in twitter bootstraps popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Lets say you have a unordered list with just icons (here only one):

```
<ul>
     <li class="in-row"><a href="#" id="meddelanden" data-content="Content here..." 
          data-title="Meddelanden" data-toggle="clickover" data-placement="left">
          <i class="icon-globe"></i></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

With these included files to your html document:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
         $('#meddelanden').popover('animate');
    </script>
```

It does appear fine and the content is shown when i press the icon, but i would like to have some links and breaks and stuff in that popover container. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Try using the popover `content` and `html` attributes...
<kbd>[See Doc](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)</kbd>

http://jsfiddle.net/4jhzg/

**html**

```
<ul>
     <li class="in-row"><a href="#" id="meddelanden"  
          data-title="Meddelanden" data-toggle="clickover" data-placement="right">
         <i class="icon-globe"></i></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
var elem = '<div><a href="google.com">google</a></div>';
$('#meddelanden').popover({animation:true, content:elem, html:true});
```

Comment: I accept this answer when the code gets more readable with this solution.

Comment: Would you please have a look at my other question? [Here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226474/how-can-i-close-a-bootstrap-popover-with-a-button-inside-the-popover)@PSCoder

Comment: I did post a answer, have a look if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use javascript for that. You can use `data-html` and `data-content` in order to achieve that.

Try setting `data-html="true"` and insert escaped html into your `data-content` attribute.
Just like this:

```
<ul>
     <li class="in-row"><a href="#" id="meddelanden" data-content="&lt;hr&gt;Sample html&lt;br&gt;" 
          data-title="Meddelanden" data-toggle="clickover" data-placement="left" data-html="true">
          <i class="icon-globe"></i></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Some text editors provide built-in HTML Escape tools. If your editor doesn't, you can use an online tool like this one:
http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html

---

***Update:***
Another approach is to add your markup to the html document itself (as a hidden container)
and create the tooltip using javascript:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tooltip-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Tooltip content goes here</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#element').tooltip({
  html: true,
  title: $('#tooltip-content').html()
});
```

This is a better approach (in my opinion). Easier to read and maintain - no HTML inside your javascript or inside the attribute `data-content`.

Comment: I wouldn't go with this approach What if the html is long, your markup will be unreadable and difficult to maintain.

Comment: It depends on the perspective. HTML inside javascript code could also be difficult to maintain. Anyway, the documentation at [bootstrap#popovers](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) shows how to set the content using javascript.

Comment: Yuo dont have to place the html inside the JS code. its just the fiddle you can just have the markup in your html itself and use $ to fetch it. you can avoid the extra overhead escaping the html tags. Just my point of view :)

Comment: +1 for that htmlescape solution and link to that tool, very helpful! The other answer, which i accepted could be "better", readability of the code. Thank you tho!