# How can i close a bootstrap-popover with a button inside the popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jhzg/28/) where i use twitter bootstrap popover function on an icon.

```
<div style="margin-top:200px">
    <ul>
        <li class="in-row">
            <a href="#" id="meddelanden" data-title="Meddelanden" data-toggle="clickover" 
            data-placement="right"><i class="icon-globe"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var elem = '<div class="well"><a href="google.com">Message one, From someone.</a></div>'+
    '<div class="well"><a href="google.com">Message one, From someone.</a></div>'+
    '<button id="close-popover" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right">Close please!</button>';

$('#meddelanden').popover({animation:true, content:elem, html:true});
```

I do not seem to be able to close the popover with the button inside it. I have tried making a jquery click function on the id "close-popover" but noting happens. (I did not include my attempt to close it inside the jsfiddle)

Any suggestions for how you can close a popover with a button inside the popover?

Regards,
Bill

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:- http://jsfiddle.net/6hkkk/

```
var elem = '<div class="well"><a href="google.com">Message one, From someone.</a></div>'+
    '<div class="well"><a href="google.com">Message one, From someone.</a></div>'+
    '<button id="close-popover" data-toggle="clickover" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" onclick="$(&quot;#meddelanden&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">Close please!</button>';



$('#meddelanden').popover({animation:true, content:elem, html:true});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm while none of the other suggestions did. I'm very grateful for all your help! /Bill

Comment: No problem, I am glad that it was of some help to solve your issue... :)

Comment: The better approach would be to add class "close" to the button and add this handler for close action:

$(document).on("click", ".popover .close" , function() { $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide'); });

Comment: This looks a perfect solution but wondering what if I place the code in directive and it can be commonly used. As I have a similar requirement in Ang and I have placed the code in directive the popover working good but only the close event is failing, any link/suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

How about just a little onclick:

```
<button onclick="$('#meddelanden').popover('hide');" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right">Close please!</button>
```

Or how about a function:

```
<button onclick="close_please();" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right">Close please!</button>
```

with...

```
function close_please() {
    $('#meddelanden').popover('hide');
}
```

Or how about binding to the button after it has been created.

```
$('#meddelanden').popover({animation:true, content:elem, html:true});
$('#close-popover').bind('click', function(){
    $('#meddelanden').popover('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Previous examples have two main drawbacks:**

1. The 'close' button needs in some way, to be aware of the ID of the referenced-element.
2. The need of adding on the 'shown.bs.popover' event, a 'click' listener to the close button; which is also not a good solution because of, you would then be adding such listener each time the 'popover' is shown.

**Below is a solution which has not such drawbacks.**

By the default, the 'popover' element is inserted immediately after the referenced-element in the DOM (then notice the referenced-element and the popover are immediate sibling elements). Thus, when the 'close' button is clicked, you can simply look for its closest 'div.popover' parent, and then look for the immediately preceding sibling element of such parent.

Just add the following code in the 'onclick' handler of the 'close button:

```
$(this).closest('div.popover').prev().popover('hide');
```

**Example:**

```
var genericCloseBtnHtml = '<button onclick="$(this).closest(\'div.popover\').prev().popover(\'hide\');" type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';

$loginForm.popover({
    placement: 'auto left',
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    title: 'Alert' + genericCloseBtnHtml,
    content: 'invalid email and/or password'
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, this won't work if you set data-container so that the popover is not next to its trigger button (in my case I set data-container="body" to make it display above the trigger container). Is there a way to actually retrieve the popover in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();" value="close">
```

by passing $(this) your referencing the button and parent references the element the button sits in

Comment: I edited.. had the syntax wrong.. this should work by closing the parent element of the button

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do the trick. It does not close all of the popover (only it's parent, not the header and such). Neither can you get the popover back, clicking the icon again.

Comment: dam I didnt see your jfiddle link
but yea.. $('#meddelanden').popover('hide'); is the way to go..
you should accept jon__o as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without calling function on click:

Javascript

```
var $popoverParent = $('.popover-parent').popover();

//allow to close when close button clicked
//register listener before popover shown
$popoverParent.on('shown.bs.popover', function()
{
    //get the actual shown popover
    var $popover = $(this).data('bs.popover').tip();

    //find the close button
    var $closeButton = $popover.find('.close-btn');

    $closeButton.click(function(){
        $popoverParent.popover('hide');
    });
});

//show your popover
$popoverParent.popover('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the popover is not aware of the ID of the referenced-element, or if it is directly under the body, one could use the aria-describedby.

```js
$('#close-popover').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).closest('.popover').attr('id');
  var toggler = $('*[aria-describedby="' + id + '"]');
  toggler.popover('hide');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have many popovers on my site, and they all have the same custom title bar, so they all have the same close button. Therefore, I can't pass an ID to an onclick handler. Instead, I decided to search for the open popover (only one can be open at a time) and then close it.

```
function closeMe() {
  $( document ).find('.popoverIsOpen').popover( 'hide' );
}
```